# Unknown GAM error in program R

Tags: r, poisson, gam

I'm conducting GAM modeling using a poisson error distribution with cubic regression splines, using count data of common ravens. I keep getting an odd error that I've never seen before in addition to some warnings. Here's my code:

> 

```
mModel1=gam(RAVENS~s(Avg_HUMind,fx=FALSE,bs="cr")+s(ROADS,fx=FALSE,bs="cr")+s(AGR_ha,fx=FALSE,bs="cr")
+             +s(URBLow_ha,fx=FALSE,bs="cr")+s(URBHigh_ha,fx=FALSE,bs="cr")
+             +s(WATER_ha,fx=FALSE,bs="cr")+s(FOREST_ha,fx=FALSE,bs="cr")
+             ,family=poisson,method="ML",data=mediumdata)
```

Error in if `(abs(old.score - score) > score.scale * conv.tol) { :` 
  `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Can someone help me with the Error that is being returned? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you provide a subset of your data which reproduces the problem?

Comment: You need to provide at least the warning messages. Those most likely contain the reason for the error. Have you looked at `na.omit(mediumdata)` to see how many complete observations you have?